# How to repair leaking roof on 1994 Kountry Coach RV?

Tags: water-leak, water, rv

We have a 40 foot 1994 Kountry Coach RV - the middle of the RV above the bathroom is where the leak is coming from - next to the skylight above the shower as well as the vent above the toilet.  Currently it is a drip and we have used RV roof patching kit which the leak has slowed but worried about over time especially with winter around the corner.  Any repair instruction or patches would be appreciative.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is your roof aluminum? I'm thinking you'd have to know *exactly* where the leak is coming from, then probably clean everything out of that area and reseal with what you were using in the first place. I wouldn't know for sure, though.

Comment: The roof is made of rubber TPO - no aluminum that I can spot thus far.  I have narrowed the lead down to the skylight (lead is coming around the seals on skylight) I have started to clean everything from that area and will re seal once finished.  Thank you for your help on this!

Comment: If it is coming directly from the skylight, you might want to see if there is a seal associated with it (between the skylight and the body of the vehicle). There may be a need to remove the skylight, replace the seal, then re-install the skylight.

Comment: I'm with @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 on this one, taking the skylight off is the better long-term strategy, you can clean and seal it better, but also visually check the area for damage and rot.

Comment: There are not really any shortcuts like just slapping some sealant on.  You need to peel back and cut away all the rotted, damaged, hardened, material and re-seal it properly from the base material up.  Yes, it's a lot of work but that's what is needed if you want a reliable fix.